# Selecting a Dictionary of Dictionaries with Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

I have the following Structure:

```
Dictionary<string,Dictionary<int,MyObject>> GetItForMe;
```

This would be very simple to do via a foreach, however I would like to do it in one query via linq.

So, I would like to retrieve, via linq, when MyObject meets my filters. So for instance:

```
MyObject.Number == 1 && MyObject.ThisString == "MyString"
```

I would like the matching records to return the above data structure - so the query returns a Dictionary of Dictionaries as above. I don't want it to simply return the matching MyOjbect's only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var result = GetItForMe.Where(x=>x.Value
                                  .Where(y => y.Value.Number == 1 
                                           && y.Value.ThisString == "MyString"))
                       .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Essentially we apply a `Where` filtering, in order to sort out the objects that we don't want to be included in the second dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EW3Jg5)

Probably you are looking for something like this

```
GetItForMe.Where(k => k.Value.Any(ik => ik.Value.MyNum == 1 && ik.Value.MyString == "bar")).ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value);
```